# в css можно сделать такую стрелку?

Tags: html, css, css3, svg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

или проще скопировать картинку?

Comment: Добавьте полную картинку

Comment: Для подобного вроде бы есть SVG

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Решение SVG

- Загружаем картинку в векторный редактор и наносим контрольные точки,
  повторяющие форму фигурной стрелки
- Сохраняем файл в формате svg
- Из этого файла забираем только `<path>` в новый файл svg  (для того,
  чтобы избавиться от кучи служебной информации редактора `Inkscape` )
- Обертываем файл в контейнер, у которого задаем ширину и высоту в %
  для   для адаптивности стрелки и регулировки размера.
- Для обеспечения независимости толщины линий при сильном уменьшении
  масштаба, добавляем свойство :  `vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke;`

```css
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;

}
#arrow {
fill:#F0ECEC;
stroke:black;
vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 401 350" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
 
<defs>
<path id="arrow"  d="m25.2 40.8 240.3 0c4.5 0 9.6 5.1 9.6 9.6l0 216.5 90.5-61.5 2.6-0.7 0.4 2.2-93.4 83.1c0 0 0 11.2 0 17.1 0 4.1-5.6 7.4-9.6 7.4l-240.3 0c-3.9 0-8.9-3.6-8.9-7.4l0-256.6c0-4.4 4.5-9.6 8.9-9.6z" /> 

</defs>

<use xlink:href="#arrow" /> 

</svg> 
</div>
```

- Патч стрелки размещен в секции `defs` поэтому мы может его
  многократно клонировать (при необходимости), вызывая командой `<use>`
- Перемещать указатель-стрелку -      `<use xlink:href="#arrow"
  transform=" translate(140 120)  scale(1 1)" />`
- Масштабировать с одновременным перемещением -
  `transform=" translate(140 120)  scale(0.15 0.15)" />`

Отражать по вертикали и горизонтали -

`transform="scale(1 -1)" />`

**Ниже пример с картой в качестве подложки**

```css
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;

}
path {
fill:#F0ECEC;
stroke:black;
vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke;
} 

#Big_arrow {
fill:transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 401 350" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" border="1">
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXXJF.jpg" width="401" height="350" /> 
<defs>
<path id="arrow" transform="scale(0.15 0.15)" d="m25.2 40.8 240.3 0c4.5 0 9.6 5.1 9.6 9.6l0 216.5 90.5-61.5 2.6-0.7 0.4 2.2-93.4 83.1c0 0 0 11.2 0 17.1 0 4.1-5.6 7.4-9.6 7.4l-240.3 0c-3.9 0-8.9-3.6-8.9-7.4l0-256.6c0-4.4 4.5-9.6 8.9-9.6z" /> 
<path id="Big_arrow" transform="scale(0.5 0.5)" d="m25.2 40.8 240.3 0c4.5 0 9.6 5.1 9.6 9.6l0 216.5 90.5-61.5 2.6-0.7 0.4 2.2-93.4 83.1c0 0 0 11.2 0 17.1 0 4.1-5.6 7.4-9.6 7.4l-240.3 0c-3.9 0-8.9-3.6-8.9-7.4l0-256.6c0-4.4 4.5-9.6 8.9-9.6z" />
</defs>

<use xlink:href="#arrow" transform=" translate(140 120)  scale(1 1)" /> 
<use xlink:href="#arrow" transform="translate(120 120) scale(1 -1) " /> 
<use xlink:href="#arrow" transform="translate(240 180) scale(1 1) " />  
<use xlink:href="#Big_arrow" transform="translate(200 0)" />

</svg> 
</div>
```

Для прозрачности стрелки указателя применено свойство:

```
#Big_arrow {
    fill:transparent;
    }
```

**Решение полностью адаптивно и работает во всех современных браузерах.**

Вёрстка никогда не сломается при уменьшении или увеличении масштаба, так как картинка и указатели находятся в одном файле svg.

Comment: градиент на Svg можно сделать?

Comment: @Vlad467 конечно можно, вы теоретически спрашиваете или хотите добавлять новые условия, которых не было в вопросе?

Answer (score 3):

### Вариант с градиентами

К поверхности стрелок -указателей добавляем линейный градиент:

```
<linearGradient id="gray" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="1" x2="0" y2="0">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#C4BFBF"/>   
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FCF8F8"/>   
        </linearGradient>
```

Команда применения градента - `fill="url(#gray)"`

**Внизу полный код с градиентами**

```css
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

#arrow, #Big_arrow  {
stroke:black;
vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 401 350" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" border="1">
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXXJF.jpg" width="401" height="350" /> 
<defs>
<path id="arrow" transform="scale(0.15 0.15)" d="m25.2 40.8 240.3 0c4.5 0 9.6 5.1 9.6 9.6l0 216.5 90.5-61.5 2.6-0.7 0.4 2.2-93.4 83.1c0 0 0 11.2 0 17.1 0 4.1-5.6 7.4-9.6 7.4l-240.3 0c-3.9 0-8.9-3.6-8.9-7.4l0-256.6c0-4.4 4.5-9.6 8.9-9.6z" fill="url(#gray)" /> 
<path id="Big_arrow" transform="scale(0.5 0.5)" d="m25.2 40.8 240.3 0c4.5 0 9.6 5.1 9.6 9.6l0 216.5 90.5-61.5 2.6-0.7 0.4 2.2-93.4 83.1c0 0 0 11.2 0 17.1 0 4.1-5.6 7.4-9.6 7.4l-240.3 0c-3.9 0-8.9-3.6-8.9-7.4l0-256.6c0-4.4 4.5-9.6 8.9-9.6z" fill="url(#gray)" /> 
<linearGradient id="gray" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="1" x2="0" y2="0">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#C4BFBF"/>   
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FCF8F8"/>   
        </linearGradient>
</defs>

<use xlink:href="#arrow" transform=" translate(140 120)  scale(1 1)" /> 
<use xlink:href="#arrow" transform="translate(120 60) scale(1 1) " /> 
<use xlink:href="#arrow" transform="translate(240 180) scale(1 1) " />  
<use xlink:href="#Big_arrow" transform="translate(200 0)" />

</svg> 
</div>
```

*Как и в примере решения без градиентов, стрелку-указатель можно перемещать с помощью команды:*

```
 <use xlink:href="#arrow" transform=" translate(140 120)/>
```

Comment: Так в задаче не просили `gradient`, или я не так понял?

Comment: @Arthur так топикастер спросил - можно ли сделать градиент, ну я и сделал второй вариант

Comment: прошу прощения, слепой))

Answer (score 1):

Как делать геометрические фигуры через css написано [тут](https://habr.com/post/126207/)  так что можете сделать такой вот кривой треугольник в псевдоэлементе `:before` или  `:after` и спозиционировать его к основному блоку, но что будет вам проще я не знаю все зависит от всей картины целиком

Comment: благодарю за полезную ссылку. Но всё же попробую сделать ответ на svg

Comment: будет интересно увидеть реализацию. и кстати любопытно что будет более легким в плане загрузки